# Are parametrized and unparametrized versions of the same interface possible in Java?

Tags: java, generics

**Question**

If one defines a `public class Something <T> { ... }`, then Java will complain about using a raw type if you do this: `Something noparam = new Something();`

Is it possible to define an interface or class that can be used with or without a type parameter?

**Context**

The frontend of a Java app interfaces asynchronously with our backend using callbacks:

```
public interface ResultCallback <T> {
    public void onResult(T result);
    public void onError();
}
```

Here's an example of the backend I'm talking about, with some basic CRUD operations using the callback above:

```
public interface Backend {

    // create a new Comment for a specified blog Post
    public void createComment(Post post, ResultCallback<Comment> callback);

    // retrieve the Comment with the specified UUID
    public void getComment(UUID id, ResultCallback<Comment> callback);

    // delete the Comment with the specified UUID
    public void deleteComment(UUID id, ResultCallback callback);
}
```

Notice that the delete operation's `callback.onResult(T result)` **will not have a `Comment` parameter**.  It might make sense to parametrize that result with a `Comment` and just "return" the deleted `Comment`, even if it's just to satisfy the type parameter constraint of `ResultCallback`.  I don't like this idea because the `Comment` is gone from the backend and no changes to it will persist.

Just for a usage example, the idea is that `ResultCallbacks` are defined in the frontend of the app and passed to the async backend.  For example, to display a comment:

```
public CommentRenderer implements ResultCallback<Comment> {
    @Override
    public void onResult(Comment comment) {
        // display the comment, commenter, date, etc. on screen
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message) {
        // display an error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the closest thing to that comes to mind would be to use `ResultCallback<Void>` but that would still require you to give the `onResult` a null-argument which is kind of ugly.

In this case I would recommend you to either use a separate interface for the `delete` case or let `ResultCallback` have more than one method:

```
interface ResultCallback<T> {
    void onResult(T t);
    void onDelete(); // Called after delete.
    void onError(String message);
}
```

If you think it is frustrating to override the `onDelete` even though you're rarely interested in "listening" for these type of events, you could give it an empty default implementation:

```
...
    default void onDelete() {
        // do nothing by default
    }
...
```

An alternative for pre-Java 8, is to use an `Adapter` which would look like follows:

```
abstract class ResultAdapter<T> implements ResultCallback<T> {
    @Override
    public void onResult(T t) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String msg) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering OP is using Java 8.

Comment: otherwise OP should use an Adapter

Comment: What does the Adapter achieve?  As far as I can see it's just wrapping the ResultCallback.

Comment: It allows you to write for instance [this](http://pastebin.com/ckCsbCxY) instead of [this](http://pastebin.com/6N8h7CNE). This is widely used in the Swing API. See for instance [`MouseAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `ResultCallback<Void>` and use `null` in that case.

Comment: I've been thinking about the three answers available so far - I think I like this one the most.  I'll mull it over a bit more before accepting though.  If anyone has any reasonable objections to this, please comment.

Comment: I have no objections ;)

Answer (score 1):

How a bout extended Generic Type?

```
public class Foo<T extends Comment> { ... }
public class FooDefault extends Foo< Baz > { ... }
```